# Camera.open returns null sometimes

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, camera

I'm getting a lot of crash reports on crashlytics where the Camera object is null. It doesn't happen to me during testing and using the app.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {packageName/activityName}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3026)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3057)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()' on a null object reference
   at activityName.o(SourceFile:612)
   at activityName.u(SourceFile:772)
   at activityName.onResume(SourceFile:539)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1241)
   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6106)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3015)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3057)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

The crash happens at `camera.getParameters()`.

So is it basically because the camera can't connect at the moment for some reason?

Is it similar to ["Can't connect to camera."](https://imgur.com/0ei4qr7) error you get on the camera app on the phone?

Hope someone can shed some light on this and share some ways to handle this.

Comment: From your log it looks like that the Camera object is null because the activity (of which the Camera object was a field) was destroyed and recreated. This may happen if the activity configuration is changed (typically portrait to landscape).

Comment: @AlexCohn The activity in question doesn't get destroyed when the orientation changes because I've added the configChange attribute in the manifest so that can't be the reason.

Comment: Your activity crashes in onResume(), on line 539. This happens because the camera object is null at this point. While you believe that you took care of all possible glitches, some Android OS flavour has found some impossible one. It is impossible to propose a fix without the source code.

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you initializing the camera as?

```
 camera = camera.open();
```

2) Have you used Camera Permissions?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

3) Make sure your not doing this after opening camera immediately:

```
camera  = null;
```

4) Try setting orientation of camera in portrait mode explicitly in manifest.xml

5) If you are using Marshmellow you will need runtime permissions for accessing camera.

Comment: Doing all of the above.

Comment: The crash doesn't happen all the time. This solution implies that it happens all the time on certain devices, but that's not the case. Many users have nexus 5 and the app is working fine but there is one user with nexus 5 who has faced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue.
If you use camera in activiy or fragment, you should release it.
In my case, I didn't add "mCamera.stopPreview(); and mCamera.release()" on onDestroy function.

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect#java

```
@Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        if (mCamera != null) {
            // Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    }

    /**
     * When this function returns, mCamera will be null.
     */
    private void stopPreviewAndFreeCamera() {

        if (mCamera != null) {
            // Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
            mCamera.stopPreview();

            // Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other
            // applications. Applications should release the camera immediately
            // during onPause() and re-open() it during onResume()).
            mCamera.release();

            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
```